# Android Emulator won't start after Android Studio 2.0 upgrade

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I recently upgraded Android Studio to 2.0 (Windows) which broke the emulator.
The symptom is that the emulator starts a (single thread) process that takes about 100% of its CPU. Nothing shows on the screen.
Of course, this worked like a charm before the update.

Few things I tried:

- Used an AVD created before and after the update
- Increased AVD memory to 1G
- Delete / Install Android Studio
- Used different CPU Architecture (Arm & x86)
- Used different versions of API (21 & 23)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A temporary solution:

1. Go into the AVD Manager, select the Virtual device, and click "Edit"
2. Find "Emulated Performance" -> Graphics, and switch that from auto (or hardware) to Software.

It won't have quite the performance, but this worked for me. Seems to be that Android Studio 2.0 doesn't play well with certain graphics cards or something.

Comment: That was it, Thanks for the nice catch.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem I had to   reinstall android studio all over again, After that open your  SDK monitor press on launch stand alone SDK manager, There scroll down and check if the emulator is installed properly if not install it.
I hope this answer helped you since that's what I did and it works.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I double checked everything including the SDK installation.

Comment: I will try to find another solution