# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main loop'. No response for 15000 ms

Tags: android-studio

i use windows 8.1 and Android studio 3.0.1 and shows Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread QEMU2 main loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956847/android-studio-emulator-error-detected-a-hanging-thread-qemu2-main-loop)