# Android Studio emulator error message

Tags: android

When I run the emulator I am getting this error message :
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU1 thread'. No response for 15001 ms

Can someone help please I have no idea what the problem is 
I have seen similar question but the error message is different, please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread QEMU2 main loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956847/android-studio-emulator-error-detected-a-hanging-thread-qemu2-main-loop)

Comment: The error message is different

Comment: Update your emulator to the latest version. Also update intel HAXM accelerator. Check now,