# Emulator doesn't boot properly "ERROR: detected a hanging thread"

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I cannot properly start an emulator on my Mac Mini.
When I execute the emulator command, the emulator window appears, the boot animation starts, but after a while I get this error messages:

```
ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU0 thread'. No response for 15011 ms
```

And the emulator either quits or becomes completely unresponsive.

The Mac Mini is of late 2012, has 16GB RAM, a 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5 CPU with an HD 4000 graphics card; Not the fastest, but should be able to run the emulator (and has been able to do that without problems in the past)

I tried:

Updating the emulator:

```
emulator -version
Android emulator version 28.0.25.0 (build_id 5395263) (CL:77b96786ddf712e1477c6e05cddb09526043faef)
```

Verify Intel Haxm is installed:

```
 kextstat | grep intel
  102    0 0xffffff7f83833000 0x28000    0x28000    com.intel.kext.intelhaxm (7.3.2) 58DFBE80-E54A-3EFE-B38A-215C5ED8E828 <7 5 4 3 1>
```

Running the emulator without audio and window:

```
emulator -no-audio -no-window  -no-boot-anim @avd
```

(same results)

Lowering the resolution of the avd:

```
hw.lcd.density = 240
hw.lcd.height = 960
hw.lcd.width = 540
```

in config.ini of the avd

Disabling/Enabling IPv6 doesnt change anything.

Full config.ini:

```
PlayStore.enabled = false
abi.type = x86
avd.ini.encoding = UTF-8
hw.accelerometer = yes
hw.audioInput = yes
hw.battery = yes
hw.cpu.arch = x86
hw.dPad = no
hw.device.hash2 = MD5:1c925b9117dd9f33c5128dac289a0d68
hw.device.manufacturer = Google
hw.device.name = Nexus 5
hw.gps = yes
hw.lcd.density = 240
hw.lcd.height = 960
hw.lcd.width = 540
hw.mainKeys = no
hw.sdCard = no
hw.sensors.orientation = yes
hw.sensors.proximity = yes
hw.trackBall = no
image.sysdir.1 = system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86/
tag.display = Google APIs
tag.id = google_apis
hw.gpu.mode = host
hw.gpu.enabled = yes
skin.dynamic = yes
hw.ramSize = 2048
```

Full output of the emulator command:

```
 emulator @avd
2019-04-05 14:42:46.888 qemu-system-x86_64[72065:9498885] GetInputSourceEnabledPrefs user file path = /Users/dgns/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist
2019-04-05 14:42:46.888 qemu-system-x86_64[72065:9498885] GetInputSourceEnabledPrefs effective user id path = 501
2019-04-05 14:42:46.888 qemu-system-x86_64[72065:9498885] GetInputSourceEnabledPrefs user pref content = <CFBasicHash 0x7fa6a164d730 [0x7fffaa5028e0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x7fa6a1616070 [0x7fffaa5028e0]>{contents = "AppleSavedCurrentInputSource"} = <CFBasicHash 0x7fa6a164d6f0 [0x7fffaa5028e0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x7fffaa570f68 [0x7fffaa5028e0]>{contents = "InputSourceKind"} = <CFString 0x7fffaa5b64a8 [0x7fffaa5028e0]>{contents = "Keyboard Layout"}
    1 : <CFString 0x7fffaa56bc68 [0x7fffaa5028e0]>{contents = "KeyboardLayout Name"} = Austrian
    2 : <CFString 0x7fffaa5a25e8 [0x7fffaa5028e0]>{contents = "KeyboardLayout ID"} = <CFNumber 0x5c37 [0x7fffaa5028e0]>{value = +92, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
}

}
emulator: INFO: boot completed
emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU0 thread'. No response for 15011 ms
emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU1 thread'. No response for 15011 ms
emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU0 thread'. No response for 15011 ms
```

```
which emulator
/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator
```

Expected Result: Emulator Boots and is able to run the automated tests afterwards

Actual Result: Emulator quits or hangs

Comment: Run `emulator-check accel hyper-v cpu-info window-mgr desktop-env` to check if emulator binary sees haxm acceleration

Comment: have you seen this link?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956847/android-studio-emulator-error-detected-a-hanging-thread-qemu2-main-loop

Comment: looks ok:
accel:
0
HAXM version 7.3.2 (4) is installed and usable.
accel
hyper-v:
0
Hyper-V runs only on Windows
hyper-v
cpu-info:
146
Intel CPU|Virtualization is supported|64-bit CPU|
cpu-info
window-mgr:
0
Mac
window-mgr
desktop-env:
0
Mac
desktop-env

Comment: Yes, I tried turning on IPv6, or disabling it, did not change anything unfortunately. The problem also persists with Quick Boot

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a Mac Mini.  This is what worked for me:

Go to Tools->AVD Manager->Edit(The particular emulator)>Show Advanced Settings

Then in the Emulated Performance section, I changed it from Quick Boot to Cold Boot.

Other options if this doesn't work can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956847/android-studio-emulator-error-detected-a-hanging-thread-qemu2-main-loop).

Comment: if you find a solution, please let me know. For know, I have given up and just run my tests on real devices.

Comment: I got it working!  I updated my answer.  Fingers crossed for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone to Tools->AVD Manager->Edit(The particular emulator)>Show Advanced Settings

Then in the Emulated Performance section i had the Quick Boot selected, which i changed to Cold Boot and everything started working fine.