# Phone emulation in Android Studio is constantly crashing

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run the app the phone emulation opens up. For about 15 seconds it will just be on a black screen then it just crashes.

This is the error at the bottom of the window: *detected a hanging thread 'QMEU2 main loop'. No response.*

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956847/android-studio-emulator-error-detected-a-hanging-thread-qemu2-main-loop

Comment: I've went to this link and tried pretty much everything. I enabled and disabled ipv6, I tried cold and quick boot and everything is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

read  /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
if text inside the file is 1 then comment out

```
# net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
# net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
# net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a physical device, its much better.